# CRM 2013: CampaignActivity - Recipients/ActivityParties not registered

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I´m working on a migration from CRM 4.0 to 2013. In the former system we have some functions which access the recipients of a e-mail campaign activity via the activityid. This was, for example,  done by joining the activitypointer and activityparty like this:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" >
    <entity name="activitypointer" >
        <attribute name="activityid" />
            <filter>
                <condition attribute="regardingobjectid" operator="eq" value="d6d3c79c-        0a9a-e311-80d7-000c2982ff89" />
            </filter>
            <link-entity name="activityparty" from="activityid" to="activityid" >
                <filter>
                    <condition attribute="partyid" operator="eq" value="fa0fa058-0a9a-    e311-80d7-000c2982ff89" />
                </filter>
            </link-entity>
            <link-entity name="email" from="activityid" to="activityid" >
                <link-entity name="campaignactivity" from="activityid"     to="regardingobjectid" >
                <attribute name="subject" />
                <link-entity name="campaign" from="campaignid" to="regardingobjectid" >
                    <attribute name="campaignid" />
                </link-entity>
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

In CRM 2013 I find now, that the recipients are not registered in the activityparty table. If I look in this, I find only two references: one for the campaignactivity and one for the systemuser. Although I checked the "Track Activities" Checkbox in the confirmation window of the Mail Merge process. Does anyone know if changes have been made to handling the activity parties in CRM 2013?

A deeper search brought up, that the activities are tracked, but the regardingobjectid in activitypointer - which should referr to the activity - is empty. So that there is no realtion now between the activity and the activity parties.. which is really weird and a problem for me now.